# Node module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv, sanity

I am this error when i am trying to run the sanity.io in node.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Require stack:
- D:\APIs\node_modules\@sanity\cli\lib\cli.js
    ...... {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\APIs\\node_modules\\@sanity\\cli\\lib\\cli.js' ]
}
```

Comment: Tried `npm install`?

Comment: i deleted node_modules and install using node i but didn't worked

Comment: `npm install dotenv` ??

Comment: tried but not working